# VB Gridview Populating and Sorting

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datasource

I am having a problem getting my GridView's DataSource worked out.  I have tried multiple variations in coding, each with their own issues.  I have the DataSourceID defined using the GridView Configuration manager.  When I attempt to call my stored procedure to populate my GridView, I get no results.  So, I tried to define a DataSource in the codebehind and manually bind (and set DataSourceID = '' to avoid error).  That populates my GridView very well, but won't allow for sorting.

Here's my question:  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong so that neither of these solutions works?  I've repurposed code from another project I did, and they are identical (in other project, both DataSourceID and Datasource are used with no error?)  Here's my ASP.net Gridview and Proc code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvUserSearch" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 56px; top: 382px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 187px" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="UserSearchDataSource" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" >
    <ItemStyle ForeColor="#0066FF" />
    </asp:CommandField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubscriberID" HeaderText="SubscriberID" SortExpression="SubscriberID" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Last Name" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First Name" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="EmailAddress" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="locationid" HeaderText="Unit ID" SortExpression="locationid" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="unit_name" HeaderText="Unit Name" SortExpression="unit_name" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Birthday" HeaderText="Birthday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Birthday" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM/DD/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" HtmlEncodeFormatString="False" >
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip Code" HeaderText="Zip Code" SortExpression="Zip Code" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Status" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUnsubscribed" HeaderText="Unsubscribe Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DateUnsubscribed" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM/DD/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserSearchDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CafeWorksConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="MarketingPortal_UserSearchProc" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtEmail" Name="Email" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLastName" Name="LastName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFirstName" Name="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my VB.net codebehind:

```
Dim CafeWorksConnection As New SqlConnection()
Dim CafeWorksCS As String
Dim CafeWorksDA As SqlDataAdapter
Dim CafeWorksCB As SqlCommandBuilder
Dim CafeWorksDS As New DataSet
Dim CafeWorksSqlC As New SqlCommand
Dim CafeWorksReader As SqlDataReader

 Private Sub DBConnect()
    'Get the connection string from the web.config file
    CafeWorksCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CafeWorksConnectionString").ConnectionString

    'Assign the Connection String to the Connection
    CafeWorksConnection.ConnectionString = CafeWorksCS

    'Open the database connection
    CafeWorksConnection.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub Populate_GridView()
    'Make a database connection
    DBConnect()

    'Define the type of query being executed (Stored Procedure)
    CafeWorksSqlC.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    CafeWorksSqlC.CommandText = "MarketingPortal_UserSearchProc "

    'Define the stored procedure parameters
    CafeWorksSqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
    CafeWorksSqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text)
    CafeWorksSqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text)

    'Make a connection for the stored procedure to run
    CafeWorksSqlC.Connection = CafeWorksConnection
    'CafeWorksConnection.Open()

    'Executes the stored procedure and stores the result set
    CafeWorksReader = CafeWorksSqlC.ExecuteReader()

    'You need to bind the data to the GridView
    'Got error that DataSourceID and DataSource can't be defined (DataSourceID define in Gridview ASP.net
    'code and is not giving me a result set for some reason, so I added the DataSource and DataBind
    'gvUserSearch.DataSourceID = ""
    gvUserSearch.DataSource = CafeWorksDS
    gvUserSearch.DataBind()

    'Always close the database connection when you are finished
    CafeWorksConnection.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnNameSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNameSearch.Click
    'Call the Sub Populate_GridView to display results of search
    Populate_GridView()

    'Clear out the text boxes - Keeps data from lingering into other searches
    txtEmail.Text = ""
    txtLastName.Text = ""
    txtFirstName.Text = ""
End Sub
```

I'm still relatively new to this, and my code may not be pretty.  I would appreciate any help that anyone could give me.  Thank you!

Comment: Where are your `Columns` defined in the `GridView`?

Comment: Sorry, added the ASP.net code for my columns to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your first issue is that you do not have an `onsorting` attribute of your `GridView` defined, like this:

```
onsorting="gvUserSearch_Sorting"
```

This represents an event handler for whenever a sort operation is needed, such as the user clicking on the header of a column to sort it.

I recommend that you change your `DataSource` type to `DataTable`, because the `DataTable` data structure lends itself to having a view built against it, which you will see later is how we can easily apply the sort direction and the sort expression for the column. Here is a utility function that can return a `DataTable` to be used by your `DataSource` property:

```
Private Function GetGridViewDataSource() As DataTable
    Dim dtGrid As New DataTable()

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    ' Change this to either execute the SQL you want or change the command object to execute a stored procedure
    Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT FirstName,LastName,Location FROM Details"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSelect, con)

    Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    dAdapter.Fill(dtGrid)

    Return dtGrid
End Function
```

Note: You would need to change your `DataSource` assignment to call this function, like this: `gvUserSearch.DataSource = GetGridViewDataSource()`

Now that we have the source as a `DataTable`, we can start to manage the sorting, specifically keeping track of sort direction (ascending or descending) via a class property, like this:

```
Public Property dir() As SortDirection
    Get
        If ViewState("dirState") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("dirState") = SortDirection.Ascending
        End If

        Return DirectCast(ViewState("dirState"), SortDirection)
    End Get

    Set
        ViewState("dirState") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now we are finally ready to implement the actual sorting handler, like this:

```
Protected Sub gvDetails_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)
    Dim sortingDirection As String = String.Empty

    If dir = SortDirection.Ascending Then
        dir = SortDirection.Descending
        sortingDirection = "Desc"
    Else
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending
        sortingDirection = "Asc"
    End If

    Dim sortedView As New DataView(GetGridViewDataSource())
    sortedView.Sort = Convert.ToString(e.SortExpression) & " " & sortingDirection

    gvDetails.DataSource = sortedView
    gvDetails.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Note: What this method does is to ask the `ViewState` what the sorting direction is and then creates a `DataView` from the `DataTable` and applies the sorting expression, defined in the grid view column, and the sorting direction to rebind the data source to grid.

Comment: Thank you Karl.  I'm trying to work through your answer now.  In gvDetails_Sorting sub above, the line - Dim sortedView As New DataView(BindGridView()) appears.  I haven't defined that anywhere.  Could you please help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: Good catch, that was a copy and paste typo from example code I had developed elsewhere. Answer updated.

Comment: I finally got my "new" code to the point of not generating errors.  My problem now is when I select a column to sort, the entire GridView disappears.  Would you know what might cause this?

Comment: Are you binding the grid in `Page_Load` or no?

Comment: No.  The only code I have in the Page_Load is to set focus to a textbox.  All of my GridView populating was done either in the GridView Configuration or my sub Populate_GridView

Comment: So what actually binds the grid, clicking the search button?

Comment: Yes.  The Search buttons make everything happen.

Comment: Is your search button click calling `Populate_GridView()` or `GetGridViewDataSource()`?

Comment: Populate_GridView().  I'll try changing it to GetGridViewDataSource() now.  I tried it and now I am back to getting no result set (before I had 5 rows).  I've done something wrong, again.

Comment: I've changed the search button back to calling Populate_GridView and I'm back to having a result set, but when I sort, my GridView disappears.

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to use this code.  My problem was because I was clearing out my texboxes when I display the GridView, it wasn't sending any input parameters.  I tried using variables, but they wouldn't persist through sorting.  I ended up using hidden textboxes and that finally solved my problem.  Thank you for being patient with me Karl.  I appreciate all of your help.  I'll mark this as my answer.

Comment: No problem Wendy, glad you got it resolved. Feel free to up-vote this answer as well. :-)

Comment: Sorry Karl, I tried, but I only have 5 reputation.  But, for anyone that is reading this comment thread, this code is awesome and saved me hours of headache.  I upvote it at least +5 :)

Comment: @Wendy - no worries, just come back when you get to 15 rep. I appreciate your kind words and good luck with your coding!